# Batch file stopping after creating service

Tags: windows, batch-file

My batch script doesn't execute any line after "service.bat install". I've tried everything I could think of. If I comment out that line, then everything works. It seems as though the script stops after creating the service. Please help.

```
@echo off
net stop Tomcat7
REM ------------- Unzipping the zip file contents to a TEMP folder --------------------    
call unzip C:\Test\test.zip -d C:\Test\TEMP

REM ------------- Removing the existing folder and updating with the latest war file --   
REM rmdir /s /q C:\Test\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-test\webapps\Web
copy /y C:\Test\TEMP\Photo.war C:\Test\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-test\webapps

xcopy /y C:\Test\TEMP\Scheduler C:\BTest /E
sc queryex type= service state= all | find /I "Tomcat7"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
cd C:\Test\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-test\bin
service.bat install)   --------------------------------- execution stops here
call md C:\Test\Testing
REM shutdown.exe /r /t 00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If from a batch file you directly call other batch file, the execution is transfered to the called file and does not return to the caller.

You need to use `call service.bat install`

That way, when the called batch ends, the execution returns to the caller.